# How to paginate joined many-to-many table with where clause in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables that is joined by another one. tables are:
[image: database schema]

**PostsTable**:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Categories', [
    'through' => 'CategoryPost'
]);
```

**CategoriesTable**:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Categories', [
    'through' => 'CategoryPost'
]);
```

**CategoryPostTable**:

```
$this->belongsTo('Categories', [
    'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Posts', [
    'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
]);
```

I want to show posts that are in a specific category. for example posts in "design" category.

the route is defined as:

`$routes->connect('/blog/archive/:safe_name', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'category'], ['pass' => ['safe_name']]);`

The `category` action in `Posts` controller is defined like this:

```
class PostsController extends AppController
{
    ...
    public function category($safe_name = null)
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Photos', 'Categories']
        ];

        $posts = $this->Posts->find()->matching('Categories', function ($q) {
            return $q->where(['Categories.safe_name' => $safe_name]);
        });
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate($posts));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['posts']);
    }
    ...
}
```

but what I get is:

```
Undefined variable: safe_name [APP/Controller\PostsController.php, line 188
```

could anyone help me about this problem! and how can I do that?
sorry for bad English.

and BTW my cakephp version is 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Closures in php do not inherit variables in a higher scope

The code responsible for the error message is this:

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find()->matching('Categories', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Categories.safe_name' => $safe_name]);
});
```

Because within the closure, the variable `$save_name` isn't defined. To fix that error, use [use](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find()->matching('Categories', function ($q) use ($safe_name) {
    return $q->where(['Categories.safe_name' => $safe_name]);
});
```

Comment: tnx alot, that fixed the error, but another one poped out:


`Undefined index: pageCount [CORE\src\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php, line 634`

Comment: You aren't calling paginate, so no surprise there.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I'll update the post, and thank you for your great help!

Comment: how can I check for category and its value in view? I did this but gone wrong: 
`if($post->has('category')) { 
foreach ($post->category as $category) {
echo $category->name;
}}`

Comment: That's a 3rd question ;) - please be wary of [asking chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) - if you have a new doubt, that isn't _directly_ related to what you originally asked: ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way, I didn't know the answer to that question (it has _nothing_ to do with variable scope). Please recognize what stackoverflow is - it's not a help forum, it's a (one) question and (one) answer site.